# How to add multiple gaugeviews in xml file.?

Tags: android, gauge

I am creating an application that consists of analog gauge i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView) and i modified it on my requirements .When i click the button the needle will deflect to the value. But in my application, I want to show three analog gauges. For this i did to add the 3 gauge views in XML file but it was showing like **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0**

This is my activity;

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Evelina Vrabie
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *******************************************************************************/
package org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo;

import java.util.Random;
import org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GaugeView mGaugeView1;
    Button check;
    private final Random RAND = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGaugeView1 = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
        check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mGaugeView1.setTargetValue(0);
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            mTimer.start();

        }
    });
    }

    public  final CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {

        @Override
        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
        {   

            mGaugeView1.setTargetValue((float)25.0);
            //mGaugeView2.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            mTimer.cancel();
        }
    };
}

This is my XML:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="303dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gauge_view2" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Check" />

        <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
            android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is this error runtime?

Comment: Yup its a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml file you given GaugeView height and width as wrap_content content. Don't give wrap_content as height and width. Specify the height and width in dps like 50dp or 100dp.

Comment: I did it some how it was solved and in the "GRAPHICAL VIEW" of xml it was showing a grey color screen with no view components dude and the third gauge view was not displayed it was showing below the xml file like this:  Exception raised during rendering: 3
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: @lakshman it is the problem of the Library(GaugeView). To remove that exceptions you have to modify the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on guage view project. There was no problem to add multiple guage views. I just set the height and width of guage view according to my needs.

Comment: Can u post your modified code please dude @Kashif Ks

Comment: yeah sure.
I'm not sharing whole code. It is a xml layout of Internet speed test. But it fulfills your needs.

Comment: see my another awnser

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.kashif.InternetSpeedTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

   <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
       android:id="@+id/GMeter"
       android:layout_width="300dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/tvDownspeed"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/download" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gDownload"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="MBs"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/tvUpspeed"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/upload"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gUpload"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="MBs"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/pbwait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```